# Converting coordinates to map point on ArcGis

Tags: android, arcgis

I am trying to build an android app which tracks the device movement and draws the track on the map. I am using the ARCGIS server as my base map. Now I want to convert the coordinates received from location update on my device to map point. I am using the following code to do it. But the converted point is showing someplace else.

```
Point point = GeometryEngine.project(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(), mapView.getSpatialReference());
```

Comment: Which  mapping api do you use - google maps, osmdroid or something else?

Comment: which version of ArcGIS Runtime are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.getLatitude()` and `.getLongitude()`, those coordinates are in the WGS84 spatial reference, but most likely when you call `mapView.getSpatialReference()` you're probably getting Spatial Reference `WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere (102100)`. So try changing the third parameter -- create a new Spatial Reference with `WKID_WGS84` to match the first 2 parameters.